# capistrano cannot find previous release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I just deployed an old project using my capistrano and it deployed ok but I need to rollback. When I try to roll back using the command 'cap deploy:rollback' I get this error:

```
[Deprecation Warning] Naming tasks with before_ and after_ is deprecated, please see the new before() and after() methods. (Offending task name was before_update_code)
[Deprecation Warning] Naming tasks with before_ and after_ is deprecated, please see the new before() and after() methods. (Offending task name was after_update_code)
  * executing `deploy:rollback'
  * executing `deploy:rollback:revision'
  * executing "ls -x /home/<my user>/<my project>/releases"
    servers: ["www.my_webserver.com"]
    [www.my_webserver.com] executing command
    command finished
  * executing "rm /home/<my user>/<my project>/current; ln -s /home/<my user>/<my project>/releases/20121023110110 /home/<my user>/<my project>/current"
    servers: ["www.my_webserver.com"]
    [www.my_webserver.com] executing command
    command finished
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:rollback:revision'
  * executing `bundler:install'
  * executing "cd /home/<my user>/<my project>/releases/20121023112609 && bundle install"
    servers: ["www.my_webserver.com"]
    [www.my_webserver.com] executing command
 ** [out :: www.my_webserver.com] bash: line 0: cd: /home/<my user>/<my project>/releases/20121023112609: No such file or directory
    command finished
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2' -c 'cd /home/<my user>/<my project>/releases/20121023112609 && bundle install'" on www.my_webserver.com
```

If I start 'cap shell' and have a quick look I cannot find the 20121023112609 directory which it's looking for.

```
cap> ls -x /home/<my user>/<my project>/releases
 ** [out :: www.my_webserver.com] 20120418231223    20120419004108  20120421030033  20120422072111  20120422101603
 ** [out :: www.my_webserver.com] 20120526035027    20120526113216  20120528100439  20120528102509  20120528135335
 ** [out :: www.my_webserver.com] 20120604090722    20120724142113  20121008114048  20121008114947  20121008125600
 ** [out :: www.my_webserver.com] 20121015121531    20121015122225  20121023110110  20121023111648
```

I can see my latest deploy is there but it's called '20121023111648' and the previous deploy which I want to revert back to is called '20121023110110'.

It seems like there is a time difference or something?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your answer here [railsless-deploy](https://github.com/leehambley/railsless-deploy)

```
cap deploy:rollback
```

Run the above command for rollback.

Comment: That's what I am running but if you have a look at the output I'm getting a failed message at the end.